# How append exported reg key to file.reg

Tags: windows, regedit

Cannot find a way to append Reg export output to existing file, so i'm running this command

```
REG EXPORT HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\NvCplDesktopContext\ backup.reg
```

To export some settings to backup.reg file when it try to export something else i'm getting message that this will override the file. Anyway i can append it to file instead of rewriting reg file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about ...

```
@echo off 

REG EXPORT HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\First\ current.tmp /y
more current.tmp >> merged.reg

REG EXPORT HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Second\ current.tmp /y
more +1 current.tmp >> merged.reg

REG EXPORT HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Third\ current.tmp /y
more +1 current.tmp >> merged.reg

rm current.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gene,
Code works but I think the last line should be:

```
del /f /q current.tmp
```